# How to pile center divs in 3 float:left divs

Tags: html, css, center

The following 3 side-by-side divs are working, but i need to add more divs below the one in the center, respecting the width of the middle section. But all 3 are floated left, so i can't figure it out.

```
<div>
        <div class="left" style="width:20%">LEFT</div>
        <div class="left" style="width:60%">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div class="left" style="width:20%">RIGHT</div>
        <div style="clear: left;" />
    </div>
```

Also:

```
 .left {
        float: left;
        word-break: break-all;
    }
```

Comment: You want to add a div just below the center div?

Comment: the question is not very clear, but giving min-width:100% to the new added div might do what you want

Comment: Width is 60%. Divs coming after would be 60% as well. A bootstrap push-like class, for those coming below, with 20% margin-left, could do the trick. Otherwise, you didn't provide the whole code.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. As @designarti says, i want to add one divs in the middle section, specifically above the contentplaceholder, but also respecting its 60% size. The answer from Mark below isn't what i wanted.

Comment: If you want it above, you need to wrap them together, your div and contentholder. You practically need a 3 column fluid layout. sidebar-content(top+content)-sidebar.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, this may be what you're looking for.  I basically created another row of divs and then set the visibility of the left div to hidden.  Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hz2dz8b/)

```
<div>
    <div class="left" style="width:20%">LEFT</div>
    <div class="left" style="width:60%">middle
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div class="left" style="width:20%">RIGHT</div>
    <div style="clear: left;" />

<br />
<div class="left" style = "width:20%; visibility:hidden">LEFT</div>
<div class = "left" style="width:60%">middle
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div class="left" style="width:20%"></div>
</div>
```